# Static contents are giving 404 error for Apache proxying node JS

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy

We have an Apache proxying to the node JS service in the default SSL (443 )port. Basic authentication is enabled.

## SSL conf

SSLProxyEngine on

ProxyPass "/myApp" "https url of node JS"

ProxyPassReverse "/myApp" "https url of node JS"

However the JS files in the "Node JS application is giving 404 error which result in a blank page.

Any suggestions.

Per the log message it is expecting Apache to serve it from the default Document  root instead of node JS app. How to disable this to serve the content from the Application only.

==> ssl_error_log <==
[Sat Sep 30 00:11:53 2017] [error] [client 10.88.1.226] File does not exist: /var/www/html/bundle.js, referer: "https url of node JS"

Thanks,

Navaneeth